# How do I create a new column in r that is a binomial variable based on a string variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm currently trying to create a new column in my data frame based on another column using mutate().

I want to make the new column a binomial variable (1 or 0) based on whether the column its based on says "Active" or not. I'm currently trying to do it by saying:

```
violations$outcome = if (violations$RESULT == "Active") { 1 } else { 0 }
```

This currently produces the "Warning message:
In if (violations$RESULT == "Active Rat Signs") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" and I look at my new data frame and every `violations$outcome` is 0.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this and why my original answer isn't working? This is very frustrating and I would appreciate any comments, advice, or help you have to offer. Thank you.

Comment: `ifelse` is the vectorize `if`, so `violations$outcome = ifelse(violations$RESULT == "Active", 1, 0)`. But you can coerce a logical to numeric, so most people prefer `violations$outcome = as.integer(violations$RESULT == "Active")` because it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

R has a handy function called `ifelse`

Try `violations$outcome = ifelse(violations$RESULT == 'Active', 1, 0)`. The first argument is the condition you're testing, the second argument is what to return if it is `TRUE` and the third agrument is what to return if it's `FALSE`.

Comment: Awesome! I also found out I could do 'violations = mutate(violations, ratsigns = ifelse(RESULT == "Active Rat Signs", 1, 0))' using dplyr